# midway seems to be off when combined with the chains library

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following sample document,

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%circle
\draw[black, thick] (0,0) circle (5);    
    %binding sites
    \begin{scope}[start chain=bindingchain]
    \foreach \a/\c in {150/green, 270/red, 390/blue}
    \draw[gray] (0,0) -- (\a:5) coordinate[\c, midway, thick, draw, circle, minimum width=25, on chain];
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want the blue, red and green circle to be centred in the middle of the line. However, the blue and and red one are off:

[image: output as produced by pdflatex]

Could someone explain why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Edit: While Stefan Pinnow's answer solves my original question, as it avoids the dependence on the `chains` library, I'd still be interested in why `chains` interacts with `midway` in this way.

Comment: Why you use `on chain`" options? From your MWE seems that it is unnecessary and it cause your problem.

Comment: @Zarko Okay, in that case the minimal example was a bit too minimal. I want to reference the circles at a later point to draw connections from them to further objects. Should I update the minimal example to make this more clear?

Comment: also then there is no need for the `chains` library (see my answer). So when this still doesn't fit your needs than it would be nice/necessary to edit your question to clarify your needs.

Comment: @StefanPinnow, as I ask in my comment and indicate the cause of trubles ....

Comment: @Zarko, of course, you are absolutely right. But also after Inkane's comment there is still no need for the `chains` library which I wanted to highlight again. And so far he didn't provide an MWE where we can see _why_ he really needs the library or the use of the library makes it simpler to do some stuff.

Comment: @StefanPinnow: Well, for me there is no reason to use chains anymore, your approach works fine for me. However, I left the question open as I'm still interested in *why* it does not work with chains – simply out of genuine curiosity, and to maybe avoid similar issues with chains in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `coordinate` is a *point*. It doesn't make sense to use this for things which have dimensions. These should be *nodes*. I'm slightly surprised that the code compiles at all.

Correcting this doesn't actually change the output:

```
\draw[gray] (0,0) -- (\a:5) node [\c, midway, thick, draw, circle, minimum width=25, on chain] {};
```

but it makes more sense.

A `chain` has a direction. By default, a chain is `going right`. That means that each node on the chain is set to the right of the previous one.

Here's what seems to happen:

1. TikZ moves to the point specified as midway between the origin and `(\a:5)`.
2. It then adds the effect of `on chain` by moving right by the standard `node distance`, but it retains the default `center` anchor.

Here's a picture showing the blue circle along with two black circles. The first is drawn at (1) and the second at (2) from the movements specified above:

[image: equivalence]

Normally, the effect of `going right` would be to use `west` as the anchor, but the default `center` seems to hold here.

If you want to add nodes to a chain but do not want the chain to determine the placement of the nodes, then do not use `on chain`. Instead create the nodes first and then use `\chainin ();`.

For example, adding the `scopes` library for convenience:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[black, thick] (0,0) circle (5);
  {[start chain=bindingchain]
    \foreach \a/\c in {150/green, 270/red, 390/blue}
    {
      \draw[gray] (0,0) -- (\a:5) node (\c) [\c, midway, thick, draw, circle, minimum width=25] {};
      \chainin (\c);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: chained nodes]

If you want to make use of the `join` option, you can add it when you `\chainin` the nodes. For example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[black, thick] (0,0) circle (5);
  {[start chain=bindingchain]
    \foreach \a/\c in {150/green, 270/red, 390/blue}
    {
      \draw[gray] (0,0) -- (\a:5) node (\c) [\c, midway, thick, draw, circle, minimum width=25] {};
      \chainin (\c) [join];
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: join the chain]

Other options for chains can be added in similar fashion.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[black, thick] (0,0) circle (5);
  {[start chain=bindingchain]
    \foreach \a/\c in {150/green, 270/red, 390/blue}
    {
      \draw[gray] (0,0) -- (\a:5) node (\c) [\c, midway, thick, draw, circle, minimum width=25] {};
      \chainin (\c);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[black, thick] (0,0) circle (5);
  {[start chain=bindingchain]
    \foreach \a/\c in {150/green, 270/red, 390/blue}
    {
      \draw[gray] (0,0) -- (\a:5) node (\c) [\c, midway, thick, draw, circle, minimum width=25] {};
      \chainin (\c) [join];
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[black, thick] (0,0) circle (5);
  {[start chain=first]
    \node [on chain, thick, double, draw, circle, minimum width=25] at (270:2.5) {};
    \node  [on chain, thick, double, draw, circle, minimum width=25, anchor=center] {};
    \node (s) [thick, double, draw, circle, minimum width=25] at (390:2.5) {};
    \chainin (s);
    \node  [on chain, thick, double, draw, circle, minimum width=25, anchor=center] {};
  }
  \begin{scope}[start chain=bindingchain]
    \foreach \a/\c in {150/green, 270/red, 390/blue}
    \draw[gray] (0,0) -- (\a:5) node [\c, midway, thick, draw, circle, minimum width=25, on chain] {};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: coordinate is shortcut for `\node[coordinate]` later `circle` wins over

Comment: Then why does `\node (b) [coordinate, circle, draw] {x};` work but `\coordinate (b) [circle, draw] {x};` give an error? Or `\node [coordinate, circle, draw] {x};` work but `\coordinate [circle, draw] {x};` give an error? If it is merely a shorthand .... [Though `\coordinate [circle]` can hardly be described as a shortcut for `\node [circle]`.]

Comment: `node` and `coordinate` picks up different parts of the syntax. In `\coordinate (b) [circle, draw] {x};` because it doesn't look for a brace pair it thinks that the brace opens a new scope and trips over `x`. `\coordinate (b) [circle, draw] {};` works without a problem (or with a path instruction in it).

Answer (score 3):

This can all be done without the `chains` library ...

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %circle
    \draw[black, thick] (0,0) circle (5);
    \foreach \a/\c/\name in {150/green/a, 270/red/b, 390/blue/c}
        \draw[gray] (0,0) -- (\a:5)
            node [\c, midway, thick, draw, circle, minimum size=25]
                (\name) {}
        ;
    \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: it's actually a node so no need for coordinate

Comment: @percusse, true. Although this doesn't change the output, but maybe then there is less of a chance that someone gets confused why there is something really drawn at the `node`/ `coordinate`. Thanks for the hint. I have edited my answer accordingly.